# PanoramaGL ARC issue

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, panoramas

I got compiling issues when I'm trying to compile PLPanoramaBase library. I solved it and posted my solution to google code. But there are still somebody ask me through the email so that I decide to write my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:

1. Use -fno-objc-arc in project setting
2. Move some declaration from PLPanoramaBase.h to PLPanoramaBase.m

like this:

@interface PLPanoramaBase()
{
    PLTexture **previewTextures;
    PLTexture **textures;
}